# SSD performance

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

I recently upgraded to a Kingston Hyper-X 120GB SSD, when I run Crystaldiskmark my scores look really slow, my MB (gigabyte 775) does not have an option for ACHI in the BIOS,

I'm wondering if that's an issue. 
The scores were:

Seq read -233 write-176.8
512K-224 write-175.8
4K-25 write-80
4K-23 write-102

This drive is rated for over 500,
Any help or input would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: It would help a lot to know what motherboard you have and which port the SSD is connected to.

Comment: As @DavidSchwartz pointed out, the SATA port type is crucial here and some Gigabyte Socket 775 motherboards only have SATA II (3Gb/s) which is rated for theoretical maximum of 300MB/s. For that SSD to reach it's peak advertised performance a SATA III port is required.

Comment: those values look ok for SATA2

Comment: Yup, just looked it up, this is a SATA2 board, thanks....